# Specify local port for TCP socket client connection

Tags: node.js

How to specify the source port/local port for outbound TCP connection using node.js? This is required to support certain firewall rules.

```
net.connect({port: PORT, host: HOST}, callback)
```

I expect an additional parameter 'localPort' in the above call. But looks the API doesn't handle and the following doesn't work.

```
net.connect({port: PORT, host: HOST, localPort: 12345}, callback)
```

Using Java I would do like below:

```
Socket s = new Socket();
s.bind(new InetSocketAddress("179.11.123.102", 5000));
s.connect(new InetSocketAddress("178.1.2.102", 1234));
```

What is equivalent in node.js?

Comment: The what? A socket cannot be used for both listening and connecting at the same time.

Comment: That is not I mean, specify the local port for outbound connections

Comment: Ok. So what have you tried? This is quite well documented.

Comment: Looks you didn't understand the question...again, it is about local port which usually we dont specify as OS automatically chose. Better you mention link if you think it is documented or answer the question if you know.

Comment: @freakish When the operating system's TCP code makes an outbound connection, that outbound connection must have *remote* port (e.g., port 80 ifor HTTP) and a local *source* port (by default a randomly-assigned high-number port). I think the OP wants to know how to manually specify the local port of an outgoing TCP connection.

Comment: This appears to be completely impossible using the APIs as they currently exist. See also https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/nodejs/YK5YAcIgu90 for a discussion about how it's not possible -- the discussion is two years old, but it seems that nothing has changed.

Comment: http://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_net_createconnection_options_connectionlistener There is `localAddress` option.

Comment: @freakish Yes, exactly, there's no corresponding `localPort` option, as detailed in [this bug report](https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/7688).

Comment: @apsillers I've always assumed that an address is a pair (host, port). That naming convention is bad. I stand corrected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the bug report "[net.connect() should accept a localPort option](https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/7688)", the feature was recently added:

> Currently, net.connect has a parameter localAddress, but it should also have a localPort...
>
> It's just not released yet... [it] should be included in v0.11.13

It was added in [this commit](https://github.com/joyent/node/commit/59baab277691dcc7d788724020084414b96de22c) on February 17 and should be available in the next release of Node. If you can't wait, you can patch the diff directly into 0.10.31, and it should work as-is because the [C++ `Bind` function at the time of the 0.10.31 release](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/7fabdc23d843cb705d2d0739e7bbdaaf50aa3292/src/tcp_wrap.cc#L269-L284) supports a port argument (the patch simply augments the JavaScript layer to *use* that C++ argument).

Comment: Thank you. Any recommendation if it is advisable to patch this fix into latest stable release? Also I see only js files change. I believe there should be C++ file changes also. Are these files tracked separately?

Comment: @PhaniKumar Don't hold me liable if things go wrong (`:P`), but yeah, it looks like you could push that into the current release just fine. I think `self._handle.bind` refers to some C networking function `bind` which can take an address and a port. Node previously used the address-only variant, but it could already take a port argument as well (Node simply didn't use that argument).

Comment: @PhaniKumar Confirmed: the [C++ `Bind` function at the time of the 0.10.31 release](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/7fabdc23d843cb705d2d0739e7bbdaaf50aa3292/src/tcp_wrap.cc#L269-L284) (which is used in that patch as `self._handle.bind`) supports a port number as a second argument: `int port = args[1]->Int32Value()`